# Fixing a nullpointer exception when using image(); in processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to draw a board using 2 images for a game but I receive a null pointer exception when I call the function that creates it.

```
final int NUM_TILES = 4;
PImage image1, image2;
PImage [][] imageShown;
PImage [][] board;
int sqSide;
float randValue = random(1,2);


void setup(){
  size(500, 500);
  sqSide = width/NUM_TILES;
  imageShown = new PImage[NUM_TILES][NUM_TILES];
  board = new PImage[NUM_TILES][NUM_TILES];
  image1 = loadImage("helloseal.jpg");
  image2 = loadImage("very-rotund.jpg");
  displayPuzzle();
  
}

void draw(){
  
}


void displayPuzzle(){
  for(int i=0; i<NUM_TILES; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<NUM_TILES; j++){
      image(board[i][j], j*sqSide, i*sqSide);
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: `board` has been initialized, but there's no images there yet. That's (probably, I haven't seen the exact error message) where you hit that null. How do you define which image is where on the board?

Comment: I thought the images were loaded in setup. I was supposed to define the images in the displayPuzzle() method

Comment: [image()](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html) will "draw" the image where you want the user to see it. So far you loaded 2 images ( `image1` and `image2`) but they aren't used yet. The `image()` method should be used in relation to the `draw()` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the elements `board`. In the beginning all the elements are null. Assign an image to each element in a nested loop. For instance:

```java
void setup(){
    size(500, 500);
    sqSide = width/NUM_TILES;
    imageShown = new PImage[NUM_TILES][NUM_TILES];
    
    board = new PImage[NUM_TILES][NUM_TILES];
    image1 = loadImage("helloseal.jpg");
    image2 = loadImage("very-rotund.jpg");

    for(int i=0; i<NUM_TILES; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<NUM_TILES; j++){
           board[i][j] = image;
        }
    }   
}
```

`displayPuzzle` has to be called in `draw` rather than in `setup`:

```java
void draw(){
    displayPuzzle();
}
```